# ¿Cómo tomar elementos de la lista 1 y lista 2, y agregarlos en lista 3? windows forms C#

Tags: c#

Aquí marco todo lo que contendrá la lista 1 (Destino y Usuario), el origen lo dejé ahí como guía de que el programa funcionara. La idea es de dos listas crear una tercera que contenga: origen, destino y usuario.

Lista 1:

````
{

  class ListaSolicitudes
{
    ```static List<ListaSolicitudes> solicitudes = new List<ListaSolicitudes>();```


    string destino = string.Empty;
    string usuario = string.Empty;

    public static List<ListaSolicitudes> Solicitudes { get => solicitudes; set => solicitudes = value; }

    public string Destino { get => destino; set => destino = value; }
    public string Usuario { get => usuario; set => usuario = value; } 


    public ListaSolicitudes()
    { }

    public void Agregar(ListaSolicitudes nuevaSolicitud)
    {
        solicitudes.Add(nuevaSolicitud);
    }

}
````

}

Aquí lista 2 contiene el origen. Que es un único valor a guardar en la lista, para ser agregado a una tercera después.

lista 2:

````
        {
         class fusionaSolicitudes
       {
        ```static List<fusionaSolicitudes> solicitudes = new 
       List<fusionaSolicitudes>();```
        string origen = string.Empty;

          public static List<fusionaSolicitudes> Solicitudes { get => solicitudes; 
         set => solicitudes = value; }
        public string Origen { get => origen; set => origen = value; }


        public fusionaSolicitudes()
        { }

        public void Agregar(fusionaSolicitudes solicita)
        {
          solicitudes.Add(solicita);
       }
                    
   }
}
````

En alguna otra clase debo crear la tercer lista que contenga los datos de las  listas 1 y 2, ejemplo:

Lista 1: {Destino= Madrid, Usuario= JVazquez}
Lista 2: {Origen= Ciudad de México}

Esto que de igual a:

Lista 3: {Ciudad de México, Madrid, JVazquez}

y mostrar la tercer lista en un data grid view en un segundo form.

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Lista3.solicitudviaje;
```

Código donde se recibe la info en windows forms:
mediante un txtbox se le asigna el valor a la variable y se guarda en la lista.

````
 private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ```ListaSolicitudes nsolicitud = new ListaSolicitudes();```
            
            nsolicitud.Destino = txtDestino.Text;
            nsolicitud.Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
            nsolicitud.Agregar(nsolicitud);
            fusionaSolicitudes solicita = new fusionaSolicitudes();
            solicita.Origen = txtOrigen.Text;
            solicita.Agregar(solicita);
            MessageBox.Show(nsolicitud.Usuario + " Agregado", "Notificación",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Ex.Message, "Notificación",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
````

Comment: Agrega el código. Con imágenes es muy díficil ayudarte.De mínimo esfuerzate en eso.

Comment: Ya lo arreglé. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Si por unir te refieres a concatenar, puedes usar simplemente `Union`

Comment: No es posible unir dos listas una de tipo `List<ListaSolicitudes>` con una de tipo  `List<fusionaSolicitudes>`,  si intentas agregar un objeto a una lista y el tipo del objeto no coincide con el tipo de la lista, se lanzara una excepción. No está claro que es lo que deseas lograr, tampoco está claro para que deseas hacer algo asi, tal ves exista orta solución, pero se necesitaria tener mas información para poder ayudar.

Comment: Que tal Eduardo. Primero que nada gracias por la ayuda.    Intentando explicarme mejor, lo que necesito hacer con esas listas es tomar los elementos que contiene y añadirlos a una tercera lista.   Había pensado en algo así: Si una lista contiene "Ciudad", y otra lista contiene "NombrePersona", lo que busco es que esos elementos al recibirlos, pueda almacenarlos en un "ListaNueva" para posteriormente imprimir los datos en pantalla como cualquier lista X.  Espero haberme dado a entender más y nuevamente gracias.

Comment: @EduardoReyes Disculpa me faltó el tag

Comment: Aca hay un lio de datos importante.. a ver.. que datos tiene la lista uno? como se relacionan los datos de la lista 1 con la lista 2? Si lo que queres es unirla, simplemente recorres la lista 1, agarras el dato, te fijas cual es el de la lista 2 que corresponde, y con esos 3 datos armas la tercer lista. No termino de entender el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi L lista 1 tiene las variables; Destino y usuario. Estas se llenaran con la información que nos proporcione el usuario.  Si en la lista 1 corro el programa, recibe los datos que teclee, se almacenan en la lista 1. Y lo mismo con la lista 2 8, lo que busco es que al crear una lista 3 (con las mismas características, solo que ya incluyendo las 3 variables)

Comment: y como se relaciona eso con la segunda lista?

Comment: Obviamente esto es un ejercicio de tarea. Veo muchas cosas raras... porque lista solicitudes tiene variables que deberian ser de la solicitud? porque si la lista es estatica tenes un metodo get y set? porque es estatica? Porque agregar recibe una lista completa, y no solo una solicitud que agrega a la lista?

Comment: @gbianchi agregar recibe la lista completa para llenar cada variable al dar click en "Generar", justo como está en el ultimo código de forms.

Comment: pasate por el [chat].. todo lo que estas contando, no tiene sentido para nada...